# How do you get "onchange" behavior in Blazor pages w/o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, blazor, onchange

I'm currently building an business page for requesting funding for various departments. Depending on
the amounts populated and their values I need to populate, in real time, the **awarded amount**. I know how to do this with JavaScript, but I want to do this the right way in Blazor with the `@bind` properties and my `razor.cs` file, but whenever I try to do `@onchange` with my methods I get a nasty error:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)  RZ10008 The attribute 'onchange' is used two or more times for this element. Attributes must be unique (case-insensitive). The attribute 'onchange' is used by the '@bind-value' directive attribute.`

I have attempted other ways of doing this as well. For example the code sample below tries to use just `value=@BoardApprovedAmt` which is a property in the pages controller, and while the onchange event doesn't throw the error, it never fires the HandleInputChange() method.

`````
        <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="ceoApprAmount" class="form-label">CEO Approved Amount</label>
                <input @bind-value="@CeoApprovedAmt" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ceoApprAmount" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="boardApprAmount" class="form-label">Board Approved Amount</label>
                <input value="@BoardApprovedAmt" onchange="HandleInputChange()" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="boardApprAmount" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="awardedAmount" class="form-label">Awarded Amount</label>
                    <input value="@SourceInput" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="awardedAmount" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="requestedAmount" class="form-label">Requested Amount</label>
                    <input @bind-value="@RequestedAmt"type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="requestedAmount" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="directorApprAmount" class="form-label">Director Approved Amount</label>
                    <input @bind-value="@DirectorApprAmt" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="directorApprAmount" />
                </div>
            </div>````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to handle the bind:event.

```
@page "/bind-event"

<p>
    <label > Input 1</label>
    <input @bind="InputValue" @bind:event="oninput" @onchange="Calculate"/>
    <label> Input 2</label>
    <input @bind="InputValue2" @bind:event="oninput" @onchange="Calculate"/>
    <label> Input 3</label>
    <input @bind="InputValue3" @bind:event="oninput" @onchange="Calculate"/>
</p>

<p>
    <code>InputValue</code>: @InputValue
</p>

<p>
    <code>OutputValue</code>: @TotalValue
</p>

@code {
    private string? InputValue { get; set; }
    private string? InputValue2 { get;  set; }
    private string? InputValue3 { get;  set; }
    private decimal? TotalValue { get; set; }

    private void Calculate()
    {
        TotalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(InputValue) + Convert.ToDecimal(InputValue2) + Convert.ToDecimal(InputValue3); 

        
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to `@bind` data at all unless you need to set it programatically.  You can catch the new value in your handler: `private void Calculate(ChangeEventArgs args){}

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you cannot use both @bind-value and @onchange, because internally `@bind-value` is using `@onchange`

About the onchange not working, you're using the html element onchange event attribute, not Blazor's event handler. Replace `onchange="HandleInputChange()"` with `@onchange="HandleInputChange"`

Original:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <label for="boardApprAmount" class="form-label">Board Approved Amount</label>
    <input value="@BoardApprovedAmt" onchange="HandleInputChange()" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="boardApprAmount" />
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <label for="boardApprAmount" class="form-label">Board Approved Amount</label>
    <input value="@BoardApprovedAmt" @onchange="HandleInputChange" type="text" pattern="-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="boardApprAmount" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Venamigo, it looks like this a good partial solution but doesn't get me all the way there. When I use the value = "@fieldInput" I don't have access to this because the two-way-binding is no longer there.